# PostgreSQL group by epoch month

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch

I got a crazy amount of rows that uses epoch time.
id, customerid, orderid, uxtime

On my desk right now is to build a admin page that allows others to quickly wade through this humongous pile of rows.

They want to be able to choose year and month and get that months list.

That means: Choose 2016 and April that should return all ids from april-16.

This has be able to be done in a smart cool sql-sentence. That is where you come in. I am working on it and making some progress but I am pretty sure all of you is so much quicker than me. :)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

To convert "April 2016" to a unix epoch use `make_date()` and `extract()`

```
extract(epoch from make_date(2016,4,1))
```

You also need an upper bound for a where clause which would typically be the first of the next month:

```
extract(epoch from make_date(2016,4,1) + interval '1' month)
```

So your SQL statement would be something like this:

```
select ...
from ...
where uxtime >= extract(epoch from make_date(2016,4,1))
  and uxtime < extract(epoch from make_date(2016,4,1) + interval '1' month);
```

---

A slightly shorter way of writing it would be:

```
select ...
from ...
where to_char(to_timestamp(uxtime), 'yyyy-mm') = '2016-04'
```

The above however will be a **lot** slower the the first solution because it cant' make use of an index on `uxtime`

You *could* create an index on `to_char(to_timestamp(uxtime), 'yyyy-mm')` if you really prefer that solution to speed up the query.